LLVM constant expressions other than getelementptr
LLVM has the notion of constant expressions, https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#constant-expressions
These are a way to apply various operations including arithmetic and logic to constant operands, with a syntax that is similar to the use of those operations in instructions, but not identical, e.g. it puts ( ) around the operands.
You would think they would be used for things that are constant expressions in the C source code, like 1 + 2, but they're not. Those are just immediately evaluated by the compiler.
What are LLVM constant expressions for, then? They are used for cases where values are known constants only at link or load time, e.g.
int a[100];
int *b = a + 30;

compiles to
@a = dso_local global [100 x i32] zeroinitializer, align 16
@b = dso_local global ptr getelementptr (i8, ptr @a, i64 120), align 8

So that specifically uses a getelementptr constant expression.
Is there any source construct that will get Clang or any other LLVM-based compiler to emit LLVM constant expressions using operations other than getelementptr?

LLVN constants are used where constants are required at the end of parsing the source language. You've seen getelementptr, which requires constants for some of its parameters.
They're not used else, even though nothing forbids it, because LLVM generally tries to make parsing the source language simple. The LLVM way of life is that frontends parse, generate IR and don't think much about what IR. Later, LLVM passes think hard about how to optimise the IR.
There are ways in which source language parsers could spot and use optimisation opportunities. That's typically not done in compilers that use LLVM. Clang, for example, often generates a dead instruction at the start of functions, because the parser doesn't know whether the instruction will be alive yet.
Any frontend could supply a constant expression in place of any operand. It's legal to express 1+1+1+1 as an add with two operands, both of which are constant additions. It's just extra bother for frontends, for no benefit.
